# How do I plot this dataset in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm reading through a tutorial on machine learning that uses Python, and I'm struggling to plot the dataset that is being used.  The tutorial uses the code below to generate the datasets that are used, but doesn't show the code to plot them.

They should be plotted in 3 dimensions with the z-value always being either 1 or -1.  Here's the code that generates the dataset:

```
import numpy as np

def get_dataset(get_examples):
    X1, y1, X2, y2 = get_examples()
    X, y = get_dataset_for(X1, y1, X2, y2)
    return X, y

def get_dataset_for(X1, y1, X2, y2):
    X = np.vstack((X1, X2))
    y = np.hstack((y1, y2))
    return X, y

def get_training_examples():
    X1 = np.array([[10,10],[6,6],[6,11],[3,15],[12,6],[9,5],[16,3],[11,5]])
    X2 = np.array([[3,6],[6,3],[2,9],[9,2],[18,1],[1,18],[1,13],[13,1]])

    y1 = np.ones(len(X1))
    y2 = np.ones(len(X2)) * -1
    return X1, y1, X2, y2
```

Here's what the dataset looks like:

```
>>> get_dataset(get_training_examples)

(array([[10, 10],
        [ 6,  6],
        [ 6, 11],
        [ 3, 15],
        [12,  6],
        [ 9,  5],
        [16,  3],
        [11,  5],
        [ 3,  6],
        [ 6,  3],
        [ 2,  9],
        [ 9,  2],
        [18,  1],
        [ 1, 18],
        [ 1, 13],
        [13,  1]]),
 array([ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1.,
        -1., -1., -1.]))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how exactly you want to plot it but reading your question I think you want a scattered plot.
To do that, you should work with matplotlib and with mpl_toolkits(to make the 3d view)

the code should be like this:

```
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits import mplot3d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def get_dataset(get_examples):
    X1, y1, X2, y2 = get_examples()
    X, y = get_dataset_for(X1, y1, X2, y2)
    return X, y

def get_dataset_for(X1, y1, X2, y2):
    X = np.vstack((X1, X2))
    y = np.hstack((y1, y2))
    return X, y

def get_training_examples():
    X1 = np.array([[10,10],[6,6],[6,11],[3,15],[12,6],[9,5],[16,3],[11,5]])
    X2 = np.array([[3,6],[6,3],[2,9],[9,2],[18,1],[1,18],[1,13],[13,1]])

    y1 = np.ones(len(X1))
    y2 = np.ones(len(X2)) * -1
    return X1, y1, X2, y2

X,y = get_dataset(get_training_examples)
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
ax.scatter3D(X[:,0], X[:,1], y, c='r', marker='o') # c = 'color', marker = 'marker_form'
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you.  I didn't know how to make a plot when my x and y parameters to the scatter plot were of different shapes.